# Re-ordering Strings in PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a document full of hex colours, as shown below.

```
#123 is a nice colour but #321 is also fine. However, #fe4918 isn't a bad either.
```

I'd like to rotate them round, so that `#123` would become `#231`, effectively changing the colour scheme. `#fe4918` would become `#4918fe`.

I know that with regular expressions, one can select the the hash tags but not much else.

Comment: And what about `#fe4918`?

Comment: @karthikmanchala, apologies. There we go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex to do it...

```
preg_replace('/#([\da-f])([\da-f])([\da-f])(?:([\da-f])([\da-f])([\da-f]))?/i', '#$2$5$3$6$1$4', $str)
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/CP4xdaYg)

It works by matching case insensitive hexadecimal numbers 3 or 6 times, and then reverses them using the matched groups.

Alternatively you could match it with a simple regex and callback with `preg_replace_callback()` and use `strrev()`, but I think the above example is clear enough.

Comment: This worked for me, though I changed the order of the numbers in the replacement. Thanks!

Comment: @Lolums Sorry, I missed that detail. Glad it is working for you.

Comment: Yes, the replacement order is incorrect. Should be ```#$2$5$3$6$1$4```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of a regex and strrev():

```
#([a-f0-9]+)
```

In `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php
$string = "#123 is a nice colour but #321 is also fine. However, #fe4918 isn't a bad either.";
$regex = '~#([a-f0-9]+)~';

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex, 
    function($match) {
        return '#'.strrev($match[1]);
    },
    $string
);
echo $string;
// #321 is a nice colour but #123 is also fine. However, #8194ef isn't a bad either.
?>
```

You can do this in regex alone, but the above logic seems very clear (and maintainable in a few months as well).
See a demo on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/8oYJEY).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
#([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})([\da-f]{2})|#(\d)(\d)(\d)
```

And replace with:

```
#\2\5\3\4\1\6
```

See [RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uC6mV9/4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a branch reset group to handle the two cases with the same capture group numbers:

```
$str = preg_replace('~#(?|([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{4})|([a-f\d])([a-f\d]{2}))~i',
                    '#$2$1', $str);
```